# Chatter messes up my CSS

Tags: apex, chatter, css

On one hand side we have this portal that looks normal and the css i working fine:

[image]

But Once I've embedded in chatter it all went bad and website completely shrunk as such : 

[image]

can someone help me with fixing that problem, I found an answer to this but I'm not sure on how to execute the solution.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of hurdles to pass when embedding chatter in a page without the standard Salesforce CSS. It can be done, though.

Take a look at [this](http://www.redargyle.com/blog/embedding-chatter-in-custom-visualforce-pages/). This goes into detail on using an iframe like you mentioned. If you use this, be forewarned that you might not like the idea of a second scroll bar on your page that only scrolls the chatter iframe.

The gist of using an iframe to expose chatter is as follows:

1. Create the VF page that the user accesses.
2. Create the Visualforce page where the `chatter:feed` tag will be placed.
3. On the chatter page, leverage JavaScript to change the behavior of clicking on a link (otherwise it would just follow the link in the iframe and the parent window would remain unchanged.)
4. Embed the chatter page in an iframe in the first page. The `src` tag should point to the chatter Visualforce page.

You may want to examine alternate solutions as well. If you want the chatter feed to match your page's styling, you might be able to leverage the `feedItem` object. There are some restrictions on the object, such as SOQL query WHERE clause restrictions, but without knowing your specific requirements I cannot say if it will work for you. More on feedItem [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm).